# Closing Form/Window Through Main Window Button C#

Tags: c#, forms

I would like to ask for everyone's help . what would I wanna do is to close a random loaded window whenever I press a `.button` on the `Main Window`.  Here is where I am as of today the window name are `( im1,im2,im3,im4)`. As expected all of the window will be opened upon loading, but somewhere on my code is wrong that when I pressed the button non of the open window would be closed. Also I would like to have a `non-repeating` random code. so if i clicked the button once again it would be a 100% sure that it would not try to close the already closed window. Hope You Understand My English I am sorry.

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random g = new Random();
       int ans = g.Next(1, 5);
        if (ans == 1)
        {
            im1 v1 = new im1();
            v1.Close();       
        }
        if (ans == 2)
        {
            im2 v2 = new im2();
            v2.Close();
        }
        if (ans == 3) 
        {
            im3 v3 = new im3();
            v3.Close();
        }
        if (ans == 4)
        {
            im4 v4 = new im4();
            v4.Close();

        }

    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        im4 v4 = new im4();
        v4.Show();
        im3 v3 = new im3();
        v3.Show();
        im2 v2 = new im2();
        v2.Show();        
        im1 v1 = new im1();
        v1.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use field instead of local variable.Create them out side method . v1 v2 v3 v4 and Random.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but sorry I can't understand"Use Field", I just started Proggraming Class. Will try to look for this tho thanks

Comment: You are creating variables inside method. Put them outside method. Currently im working with my phone so unfortunately i cant give answer. Hope someone gives.

Comment: I think what he is trying to draw your attention to is the variable scoping for those that hold the windows.  For example, you are currently defining v1, v2,v3 v4 twice (once for Window_Loaded_1 and once for Button_Click_2)- Why not define them outside of those functions, in within the scope of the MainWindow class (as class variables), that way both methods will access the same window variables.  The way it is currently defined, your v1,v2,v3,v4 variables are pointing to different memory locations.

Comment: It works now , thanks for the big help!

Answer (score 1):

Fields are instance members, they are variables which can be accessed from every method of the class.

As M.kazem Akhgary suggested, your code would look like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    im1 v1 = null;
    im2 v2 = null;
    im3 v3 = null;
    im4 v4 = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random g = new Random();
       int ans = g.Next(1, 5);
        if (ans == 1)
        {
            v1.Close();       
        }
        if (ans == 2)
        {
            v2.Close();
        }
        if (ans == 3) 
        {
            v3.Close();
        }
        if (ans == 4)
        {
            v4.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        v4 = new im4();
        v4.Show();
        v3 = new im3();
        v3.Show();
        v2 = new im2();
        v2.Show();        
        v1 = new im1();
        v1.Show();
    }
}
```